# WP Ecommerce: modifying the transaction report email sent to admin upon sale

Tags: php, wordpress, e-commerce

I am looking to modify the transaction results email that is sent to the admin upon sale of an item (include and exclude certain information, etc), I've researched on google and looked on the wp-ecommerce support site and have been unable to locate where this is being done currently (a lot of references to older versions of the plugin that have since changed significantly). I will continue to look for where to do this but as I am not well versed in wp-ecommerce (or wordpress for that matter) I am not entirely sure where to look.

If anyone could shed light on this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under wp-e-commerce/wpsc-updates/updating_tasks.php

Line 356-372 is where the email section is.

```
add_option('wpsc_email_receipt', '', __('Thank you for purchasing with %shop_name%, any items to be shipped will be processed as soon as possible, any items that can be downloaded can be downloaded using the links on this page.All prices include tax and postage and packaging where applicable.You ordered these items:%product_list%%total_shipping%%total_price%', 'wpsc'), 'yes');
add_option('wpsc_email_admin', '', __('%product_list%%total_shipping%%total_price%', 'wpsc'), 'yes');

if(get_option('wpsc_email_receipt') == '') {
    if(get_option('email_receipt') != '') {
        update_option('wpsc_email_receipt', get_option('email_receipt'));
    } else {
        update_option('wpsc_email_receipt', __('Thank you for purchasing with %shop_name%, any items to be shipped will be processed as soon as possible, any items that can be downloaded can be downloaded using the links on this page.All prices include tax and postage and packaging where applicable.You ordered these items:%product_list%%total_shipping%%total_price%', 'wpsc'));
    }
}
if(get_option('wpsc_email_admin') == '') {
  if(get_option('email_admin') != '') {
        update_option('wpsc_email_admin', get_option('email_admin'));
    } else {
        update_option('wpsc_email_admin', __('%product_list%%total_shipping%%total_price%', 'wpsc'));
    }
}
```

If you want to go even deeper into the whole email code, you can also go into this section

wp-e-commerce/wpsc-includes/purchase-log-notification.class.php

Answer (score 1):

I created a plugin for this and many other wp e-commerce features.
With the [shop styling plugin](http://haet.at/wp-e-commerce-shop-styling/) you can modify the transaction report with placeholders as well as any other mails from the wordpress backend without modifying any plugin files.

Comment: You know funny you mention that. I saw your plugin, after I had made the modifications I required. It is pretty comprehensive. In the end I used it to get a better understanding of how the styling works with thewp e-commerce back-end, so I would like to say thanks for that!

Comment: Hannes How do i change the transaction email that comes to me after a customer completes a purchase? I know in your plug-in there is a transaction page tab (that i have purchased) but that seems only to be able to edit the message on website after the customer purchaces something and not the Transaction Report email.

Comment: Hi, in the current version there is a wysiwyg field to customize the transaction report in the settings page below the other email fields

Comment: @Hannes - Is this plugin still available? I tried to look in your site but it appears not to be there.

Comment: @MaorBarazany no, I replaced this plugin with WP HTML Mail but focused more on WooCommerce in the last years. If you just want to use it for general styling you can use WP HTML Mail but you can't modify any content for WP E-Commerce